# Jenkins pipeline sh step returns error "process apparently never started"

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am stuck in trying to get a Jenkinsfile to work. It keeps failing on `sh` step and gives the following error

```
    process apparently never started in /home/jenkins/workspace
    ...
    (running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
```

I have tried adding

```
withEnv(['PATH+EXTRA=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'])
```

before sh step in groovy file

also tried to add

```
/bin/sh
```

in `Manage Jenkins -> Configure System` in the shell section

I have also tried replacing the sh line in Jenkinsfile with the following:

````
sh "docker ps;"
sh "echo 'hello';"
sh ./build.sh;"
sh ```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
```
````

This is the part of Jenkinsfile which i am stuck on

```
node {
    stage('Build') {
        echo 'this works'
        sh 'echo "this does not work"'
    }
}
```

expected output is "this does not work" but it just hangs and returns the error above.

what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the default workingDir value for default jnlp k8s slave nodes is now set to `/home/jenkins/agent` and I was using the old value `/home/jenkins`

here is the config that worked for me

```
containerTemplate(name: 'jnlp', image: 'lachlanevenson/jnlp-slave:3.10-1-alpine', args: '${computer.jnlpmac} ${computer.name}', workingDir: '/home/jenkins/agent')
```

Comment: You saved my day with this answer. Thanks!!

Comment: Yeah this also fixed the prior Error I had: `[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
jenkinsAgent-jdk17-docker-00000f3a56dwi on jenkinsAgent-jdk17-docker seems to be running inside container a8a7ec563a2da833c187e59f8661d29794bb4af586f1f45faad1644d77f548ee
but /home/jenkins/workspace/simpleNodejsPip could not be found among [/var/run/docker.sock, /usr/bin/docker, /home/jenkins/.jenkins, /home/jenkins/agent]`

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get the same trouble with the malformed PATH environment variable. This prevents the sh() method of the Pipeline plugin to call the shell executable. You can reproduce it on a simple pipeline like this:

```
node('myNode') {
    stage('Test') {
        withEnv(['PATH=/something_invalid']) {
            /* it hangs and fails later with "process apparently never started" */
            sh('echo Hello!')
        }
    }
}
```

There is variety of ways to mangle PATH. For example you use withEnv(getEnv()) { sh(...) } where getEnv() is your own method which evaluates the list of environment variables depending on the OS and other conditions. If you make a mistake in the getEnv() method and PATH gets overwritten you get it reproduced.