helloworld pipeline hangs on sh command from Jenkins pipeline on a slave
I m on latest Jenkins 2.479.2 with jdk 17.
I was able to start slave node with label Prod_Slave_56 and see no errors.
Agent successfully connected and online

I created new pipeline job runs but hangs on this specific line -> sh 'echo Hello, World! from Slave' and never completes.
pipeline {
    agent { label 'Prod_Slave_56' }  // Replace with your slave label
    stages {
        stage('Hello World') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // Simple shell script to print "Hello, World!"
                    echo "Hello, World!"
                    sh 'echo Hello, World! from Slave'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

The job simply waits and hangs for a long time and fails with error. I cannot find any obvious message in the output from which i could derive any conclusions.

Output after 6 minutes of execution:
Started by user 45545423
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Prod_Slave_56 in /app/axmw/Jenkins/nodes/workspace/TEST_PIPELINE
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Hello World)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Hello, World!
[Pipeline] sh
process apparently never started in /app/axmw/Jenkins/nodes/workspace/TEST_PIPELINE@tmp/durable-d9bee59a
(running Jenkins temporarily with -Dorg.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.LAUNCH_DIAGNOSTICS=true might make the problem clearer)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code -2
Finished: FAILURE

I'm clueless and to what i should do or check inorder to resolve this as this is very basic.
Below is the output of sestatus
> sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      33

Note: This issue is occurring post upgrade of jenkins from a lower version to the latest version along with updating the plugins. It was running fine on the older version of jenkins and jdk..
Please suggest help overcome the issue.

Hi,
Please turn on "timestamp" on console output by tick "Add timestamps to the Console Output" in Job configure.
Then, capture the Jenkins log when running a build from this job.

Have you looked into this yet? https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes/#plugin-content-pipeline-sh-step-hangs-when-multiple-containers-are-used

also this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57832349/jenkins-pipeline-sh-step-returns-error-process-apparently-never-started
